# grep - only get the prefix only

Tags: terminal, grep

I know `-h` suppresses the prefix in `grep` so I would only get the filename. Is there a way to only get the prefix? I do a find for files and then pass that to grep.

Finally found it in the manual... `-l` looks like it now works

Comment: could you post your solution as an answer below and mark it as the accepted answer? It eases the life of people looking for solutions :)

Comment: This question is probably more suited to superuser.com than stackoverflow. I've voted to migrate it there, if enough others agree it will get moved automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not a flag, but how about

```
dirname

 dirname /usr/bin/sort
 /usr/bin
```